# Euclidian Distances

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new to Python and am trying my best to create two arrays of floats AND find the min euclidian distance between the two arrays. My commented code so far below. The output seems way to high at `5.5856060906150971`. Would love any input. I imagine I am doing many things wrong.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sklearn as sk
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing

//arrays
>>> data1 = []
>>> data2 = []
>>> for x in range(0,30):
...     data1.append(np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0))
...     data2.append(np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0))

//scale data 
//something wrong in here?
>>> scaledData1 = sk.preprocessing.scale(data1)
>>> scaledData2 = sk.preprocessing.scale(data2)

//calc distance
>>> distances = []
>>> for line in scaledData1:
...     distance = np.linalg.norm(line - scaledData2)
...     distances.append(distance)

//min distance
>>> np.min(distances)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numpy array instead of lists**

You can take advantage of numpy to create arrays efficiently instead of using lists. First modification of your code would be:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn import preprocessing

data1 = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,30) # array size is the third parameter
data2 = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,30) # same thing here
```

Scaling a numpy array should work better than a list. There is nothing wrong with your call to "scale"

**Compute minimal distance between arrays**

You can use [Scipy's distance matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html#scipy.spatial.distance_matrix) as follows:

First create 1d vectors from your scaled arrays:

```
scaledData1 = sk.preprocessing.scale(data1).reshape(-1,1)
scaledData2 = sk.preprocessing.scale(data2).reshape(-1,1)
```

Compute the distance matrix and get its minimum:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix # you can put that at the beginning of your code



distMatrix = distance_matrix(scaledData1,scaledData2) #l2 distance by default

minimalDistance = distMatrix.min()
```

In my test, I got 5.4e-2 as a minimal distance, which is close to 0, as one would expect for uniform distributions.